# subplots by hand in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

subplots by hand.

I am referring following link

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/04.08-Multiple-Subplots.ipynb

> The most basic method of creating an axes is to use the plt.axes function. As we've seen previously, by default this creates a standard axes object that fills the entire figure. plt.axes also takes an optional argument that is a list of four numbers in the figure coordinate system. These numbers represent [left, bottom, width, height] in the figure coordinate system, which ranges from 0 at the bottom left of the figure to 1 at the top right of the figure.
>
> For example, we might create an inset axes at the top-right corner of another axes by setting the x and y position to 0.65 (that is, starting at 65% of the width and 65% of the height of the figure) and the x and y extents to 0.2 (that is, the size of the axes is 20% of the width and 20% of the height of the figure):

```
ax1 = plt.axes()  # standard axes
ax2 = plt.axes([0.65, 0.65, 0.2, 0.2])
```

Here above example I am expecting ax2 at location starting (0.65,0.65) as we  have bottom and left at 0.65 and 0.65 but i am observing (0.65, 0.7) and lenght and height is 0.2 i.e, right vertical line at location 0.85 but i am observing at 0.9? Why is this differnces. Kindly explain.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers given to `plt.axes` are in figure units, where the figure is 1 unit wide and 1 unit heigh.
Let me just highlight the important part:

> For example, we might create an inset axes at the top-right corner of another axes by setting the x and y position to 0.65 (that is, starting at 65% of the width and 65% of the height **of the figure**) and the x and y extents to 0.2 (that is, the size of the axes is 20% of the width and 20% of the height **of the figure**)

Maybe an image helps more to understand that

[image]

---

That said there is a little subtlety when this code is being used with the inline backend in IPython or jupyter. In that case the size of the figure shown in the output may slightly differ from the original figure as it is cropped or expanded to fit nicely to everything that is drawn inside. This is equivalent to the `bbox_to_inched="tight"`  option of `savefig`. Hence, if you want to verify that the subplot is indeed placed at 65% of figure size and is 20% large, you would need to run the code as a script outside the notebook, or save the figure `plt.savefig("test.png")` (without using the `bbox_to_inched="tight"` option).

A final note: While `add_axes` may be an easy option to add an axes in figure coordintes, it is often desireable to add an inset in axes coordinates, i.e. in percentage of the axes width and height instead of the figure width and height. This can be done as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ip = InsetPosition(ax1, [0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7]) 
                        #posx, posy, width, height in coordinates of ax1
ax2.set_axes_locator(ip)

ax2.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```